# Powershell Restore Azure SQL Database to local with Restore-Database

Tags: sql-server, restore, export, azure-sql-database, powershell

I have written a powershell script that uses `Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport` & `Get-AzureStorageBlob` to export my Azure DB to a `bacpac` and download it locally, the next step is to restore the `bacpac` to my local SQL DB using `Restore-Database`, but below fails with "the media family on device is incorrectly formatted".

```
Restore-Database -dbName "MyDB" -backupFile "C:\MyAzureBackup.bacpac"
```

Is there a way to get this working with `Restore-Database`, or is there an alternative command that will do this?

Answer (score 0):

*I have not actually tried this (but it peaks my interest to later).*

You will not be able to use `Restore-Database` because it only reads native backup formats from SQL Server, not Azure SQL.

The `BACPAC` file created from your backup of an Azure SQL database is in a data-tier format. Which in this format contains the schema and data for the database. In order to restore this to a local instance in PowerShell you will have to utilize the `DAC` objects to do the `restore`. Which if you are loading the `SQLPS` module the `DAC` assembly is loaded for you.

Basic examples that I find online seem to follow this format:

```
Add-Type -path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\<version>\DAC\bin\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll"
$restoredDatabaseName = 'NewDatabase'
$bacpacFile = "Your BACPAC file you downloaded"
$conn = "Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=master;Connection Timeout=0;Integrated Security=True;"

$importBac = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices $conn
$loadBac = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.BacPackage]::Load($bacpacFile)
$importBac.ImportBacpac($loadBac, $restoredDatabaseName)

#Clean up
$loadBac.Dispose()
```

Once I get something setup I will test the above myself, just to make sure.

**Update**

The [dbatools PowerShell module](https://dbatools.io) now includes commands around managing DacPac files. This can be utilized to perform export and publish operations.

[Publish-DbaDacpac](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/blob/master/functions/Publish-DbaDacpac.ps1). I have not had chance to test this against an Azure SQL instance.

Comment: Unfortunely, it's not working: `The term 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.BacPackage::Load' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.` I used `140` as `<version>`

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy I've updated answer with info on command that may help but I have not tried it (don't have an Azure SQL server setup).

Comment: dbatools does not provide an Import for BacPac files, Only export for DacPac

Answer (score -1):

I cant take credit for this. Credit goes to David Browne.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51730309/the-term-microsoft-sqlserver-dac-bacpackageload-is-not-recognized

but this

```
$loadBac = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.BacPackage::Load($bacpacFile)
```

should be this

```
$loadBac = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.BacPackage]::Load($bacpacFile)
```

Square brackets.